# Jetty 503 service unavailable error

Tags: java, web, web-applications, jetty

I am running a web application in my local. Till now, it was been working fine. But without any change induced by me I am getting the following error:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:240)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:194)
at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:207)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:140)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:118)
at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextEntry(JarInputStream.java:142)
at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextJarEntry(JarInputStream.java:179)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.matched(JarScanner.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.matchPatterns(PatternMatcher.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.PatternMatcher.match(PatternMatcher.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JarScanner.scan(JarScanner.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:457)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:493)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:353)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
[2016-09-25 12:29:53,695] Artifact ***:war: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-09-25 12:29:53,695] Artifact ***:war: Deploy took 3,090 milliseconds
```

I am getting "HTTP ERROR: 503" error. Would anyone help me out resolving this issue.

Comment: I suspect one of the jars or they whole war is malformed. You can try starting it with debug parameters and suspend=y, attaching with your IDE of choice and examining variables to see which files it fails on

Comment: Also maybe repackaging the thing and trying from scratch will fix it

Comment: The newest release of Jetty, version 9.3.12.v20160915, improves the logging of error messages on bad jars, wars, and zips (even problematic specific entries)